# How can I retrieve data from a dynamic variable in a Firebase document using Flutter and Dart?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

//this is stores page

//each Stores have items in subcollection

//on pressed store (elevatedbutton) how to get the items in that store

I have tried to get data like this
but I am receiving only one stores data when clicked on any stores (elevatedbutton)

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:user/screens/pages/pages/grid_fire.dart';

class Stores extends StatefulWidget {
  const Stores({super.key});

  @override
  State<Stores> createState() => _StoresState();
}

class _StoresState extends State<Stores> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 27, 207, 186),
        title: const Text("Stores Near By"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const Stores(),
                      ),
                  );
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
          ),
        ],
      ),
       body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore
        .instance
        .collection("Stores")
        .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context,
                        AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        return const Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                      }
                      return GridView.count(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                        crossAxisCount: 1,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 3,
                        childAspectRatio: 3,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 1,
                        children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
                          return InkWell(
                            child: SizedBox(
                              height:200,
                               width:double.infinity,
                              child: ElevatedButton(
                                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                    shadowColor: Colors.red,
                                    backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 94, 8, 2),
                                    fixedSize: const Size(120, 34), // specify width, height
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                            20,
                                          )),
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20), //content padding inside button

                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                      context, 
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) =>  const GridFire()
                                        )
                                        ),
                                     child:
                                    Text(
                                          document["sname"],
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 30,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                            ),
                          );     
                          }).toList(),
                      
                      );
                    },
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:user/screens/pages/pages/stores.dart';


class GridFire extends StatefulWidget {
  const GridFire({super.key});

  @override
  State<GridFire> createState() => _GridFireState();
}

class _GridFireState extends State<GridFire> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        title: const Text("Grid View1"),
      actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>  const Stores(),
                      ),
                  );
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
          ),
        ],
      
      
      
      ),

      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore
                .instance
                .collection("Stores")
                .doc("shop1-phone-number")
                .collection("items")
                .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        return const Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
        }
                      return GridView.count(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                        crossAxisCount: 1,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 5,
                        childAspectRatio: 5,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                        children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
                        return GestureDetector(
                            child: SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 6,
              child: Text(
                // ignore: prefer_interpolation_to_compose_strings
              document['itemName'],
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25
                ),),
            ),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      );
                    },
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the id of the store as follows:

```
snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {                                  
   final id = document.id;                                           
   print(id); }
```

You should pass this **id** to the **GridFire** widget and replace "shop1-phone-number" with **id** in your query:

```
FirebaseFirestore
            .instance
            .collection("Stores")
            .doc(id)
            .collection("items")
            .snapshots();
```

Comment: please let me know how to obtain id of the store , where to place that code
'''
snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {                                  
   final id = document.id;                                           
   print(id); } 
'''

Comment: please let me know how to obtain id of the store , where to place that code ''' snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) { final id = document.id; print(id); } '''

Comment: You can obtain this id: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {                                  
   final id = document.id;                                           
   print(id); }